# How do you move an object from one array to array via feature?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to move an object from one array to another. Think of it like adding / moving a friend from non-friend to friend. I have two arrays, which can be seen below, and I am trying to move an object (i.e. a friend) from possible to current via it's 'id'. In the below example, I am trying to move Parker from possible to current with id = 7.

```
 state = {
     current: [
         {
             id: 3,
             name: 'peter'
         }
     ],
     possible: [
         {
             id: 7,
        name: 'parker'
         }
     ]
 }
```

My attempt below:

```
 function moveObject(state, action) {
   const { current, possible } = state;
   const movedObject = possible.splice(action.id, 1)[0];

   current.push(movedObject);

   const newState = { current, possible };
   return newState;
```

Which moves the wrong object...

Comment: Could you provide your attempt to move the object?

Comment: Sure, see edit above

Comment: you've written `possible.splice(id,1)[0]` - where does `id` come from? how do you select which id to splice?

Comment: The id is coming as a payload from my application to my store - see edit above (action payload - in the above example action.id = 7)

Comment: `splice` works off of the index of your array, therefore even in your example code it won't work as it's trying to remove array index `3` when only array index `0` exists

Comment: so what do you suggest to do instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move object from one array to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919837/move-object-from-one-array-to-another)

Comment: get the correct index using some other method like `.findIndex` and call splice with that value instead

Comment: question got closed before i could post answer, here you go:  `function moveObject({ current, possible }, action) { current.push(possible.splice(possible.findIndex(o => o.id == action.id), 1)[0]); return { current, possible } }`

Comment: Thanks - any idea why this was closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using splice, you must use the numeric index of the item that can be retrieved through `findIndex`:

```
function moveObject(state, action) {
   const { current, possible } = state;
   const movedObjectIndex = possible.findIndex(u => u.id === action.id);
   const movedObject = possible.splice(movedObjectIndex, 1);

   current.push(movedObject[0]);

   const newState = { current, possible };
   return newState;
}
```

[See splice doc on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/splice)

Comment: splice returns an array, get `possible.splice(...)[0]` instead

Comment: @Klaycon : U're right. Thanks. I've fixed the example